# "Service worker registration failed" does not provide error details in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm developing a scratch new chrome extension (one having only a service worker, using manifest version 3). Much of the time when I have its service worker crash due to my latest code addition, I find myself unable to get to a log / console view showing the crash reason. All I get is a dead link:

[image: service worker (Inactive)]

The hyperlink does not open the usual inspect view for the dead service worker. Alternatively, when I click the "Errors" button shown in the extensions view:

[image]

I just get "Service worker registration failed", but not any information about which line of code is causing the failure. Eventually I always find the error in my code by analytic means, but this really slows down my development iterations considerably. Is there a finer-grain view for this?

Manually opening the inspect view, there is nothing about the error to be found through the `Console` Nor the `Application` tabs of the inspect view.

Indeed after ticking the following option and reloading my extension ―

[image]

I do get a mention of my extension in this particular view ― after reloading my offending chrome extension ― but the details are less than revealing, as shown below:

[image]

It seems that wrapping the entire service worker code with a try catch surfaces the error details in some cases but not all.

Related Chrome issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1152202

Comment: The suggested answer adjoins manifest migration angles with this issue in a confusing way which could have merited a clean answer here, but okay leave it closed. Also sadly the suggested try catch solution does not always work.

Comment: The real solution is upgrading to Chrome 93, which at the time of writing is available on the official [Chrome Beta channel](https://www.google.com/chrome/beta/thank-you.html?platform=linux&statcb=0&installdataindex=empty&defaultbrowser=0)